# Select in socket programming hangs for sometime in windows ?

Tags: c++, sockets

A i am new to c++ programming and I have investigated a bit for hang of application while sending data thru socket programming as whenever there is a shift between primary and secondary servers while creating and connecting to a socket i am using the code below and i have seen it sometimes it is taking more time or freezing at **SELECT** location. Code is as below. And can i know when i use static class and use this from different classes to send data, will there be problem of thread safety.i.e any loss of data?. Is all the code below is necessary to just to create and connect to a socket?

```
 USES_CONVERSION;
SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddr; 

// Initialize ServerAddr
memset(&ServerAddr,0,sizeof(ServerAddr));
ServerAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(ipAddress); 
ServerAddr.sin_port         = htons((u_short)portNo);









// Create SocketPrimary
SocketPrimary = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);





if (SocketPrimary == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - WSASocket(TCP) call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
    return false;
}






// Set timeout option
if (setsockopt(SocketPrimary, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&RecieveTimeOut, sizeof(RecieveTimeOut)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - a setsockopt for SO_RCVTIMEO call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
    Close(SocketPrimary,TRUE);
    return false;
}






// Set timeout option
if (setsockopt(SocketPrimary, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&SendTimeOut, sizeof(SendTimeOut)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - a setsockopt for SO_SNDTIMEO call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
    Close(SocketPrimary,TRUE);
    return false;
}





// Set connect portno on address
if (WSAHtons(SocketPrimary, (u_short)portNo, &(ServerAddr.sin_port)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - a WSAHtons call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
    Close(SocketPrimary,TRUE);
    return false;
}






// Set non-blocking
DWORD BlockMode = 1;
if (ioctlsocket(SocketPrimary, FIONBIO, &BlockMode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed -  a ioctlsocket (non-blocking) call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
    Close(SocketPrimary,TRUE);
    return false;
}





// Connect socket
if  (WSAConnect(SocketPrimary, (struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    int ConnectError = WSAGetLastError();
    if (ConnectError != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T("Primary server connection failed -  to connect to server with error %ld"),  ConnectError);
        Close(SocketPrimary,TRUE);
        return false;
    }
}

// Wait for connect (use select as the socket is non-blocking at this time)
fd_set ConnectSockets;
ConnectSockets.fd_count = 1;
ConnectSockets.fd_array[0] = SocketPrimary;

TIMEVAL Timeout;
Timeout.tv_sec = ConnectTimeOut / 1000;
Timeout.tv_usec = (ConnectTimeOut % 1000) * 1000;






if (select(0, NULL, &ConnectSockets, NULL, &Timeout) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - a select call with error %ld"),  WSAGetLastError());
    Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
    return false;
}
else
{
    if (ConnectSockets.fd_count == 0)
    {
        LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed -  timedout to connect..."));
        Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
        return false;
    }
}





// Set blocking
BlockMode = 0;
if (ioctlsocket(SocketPrimary, FIONBIO, &BlockMode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - a ioctlsocket (blocking) call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
    Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
    return false;
}

LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, _T(" connected to primary server with local socket id %ld"), SocketPrimary);



// Return
return true;
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem your having, but you should not access the `fd_set` members by hand. Use `FD_ZERO` to initialize it and `FD_SET` to add a socket before select, and `FD_ISSET` to see if the socket is set after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try it, was that causing a delay?

Comment: In your question, your basically asking for a code review, without an attached bounty of significance, nobody's gonna read through it all. It's often better to focus on the code that's causing the problem, you can always extrapolate or ask to see more of the code, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You do know that the call to `select` is blocking, right? It won't yield control (return) until there's something to do.

Be it, read or write (connect, is included in that)

So it's not a hang or freeze, it was just designed operate like that.

*Also, why are you mixing Berkeley sockets with WSA sockets, if you're already using Winsock don't mix that with the Berkeley sockets code, it doesn't really make a lot of sense, use the functions prefixed with WSA.*

Comment: i just need to write to the connected socket, and it is very timespecific and i can see that it is taking more time there . Is there any alternative to select to avoid timedelay?

Comment: there's `WSASelectAsync` if async is what you want, but you can also use polling to determine whether the socket is ready or not. It depends what you mean by *very timespecific*...

Comment: i will use WSASelectAsync, what i meant with timespecific means it should not delay for my data sending.

Comment: If you don't want to block, use the async methods, but it won't be magically faster, it just won't block the normal execution flow.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Let me check with WSASelectAsync. Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: Hello,

the socket API is *very very* hard to understand and use. Your best choice is to use an example.

You may be interested in boost.asio for a nicer API (and also more portable)

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking the return value of `select()` for SOCKET_ERROR, but `select()` can also tell you if the timeout period occured, or if the specified socket set(s) are signaled.  You are ignoring that information.  You should also not be calling `select()` unless `WSAConnect()` reports `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, as the connection could succeed immediately adn thus not need a call to `select()` at all.

Try this:

```
// Connect socket
if  (WSAConnect(SocketPrimary, (struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    int Result = WSAGetLastError();
    if (Result != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T("Primary server connection failed -  to connect to server with error %ld"), Result);
        Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
        return false;
    }

    // Wait for connect (use select as the socket is non-blocking at this time)
    fd_set WriteFDS, ErrorFDS;
    FD_ZERO(&WriteFDS);
    FD_ZERO(&ErrorFDS);
    FD_SET(SocketPrimary, &WriteFDS);

    TIMEVAL Timeout;
    Timeout.tv_sec = ConnectTimeOut / 1000;
    Timeout.tv_usec = (ConnectTimeOut % 1000) * 1000;

    Result = select(0, NULL, &WriteFDS, &ErrorFDS, &Timeout);
    if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - a select call with error %ld"), WSAGetLastError());
        Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
        return false;
    }

    if (Result == 0)
    {
        LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed -  timeout to connect..."));
        Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
        return false;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(SocketPrimary, &ErrorFDS))
    {
        DWORD SocketError;
        getsockopt(SocketPrimary, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&SocketError, sizeof(SocketError));

        LogToEventLog(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, EVENTID_WINSOCK_ERROR, _T(" Primary server connection failed - to connect to server with error %u"), SocketError);
        Close(SocketPrimary, TRUE);
        return false;
    }
}

// connected ...
```